# Export Excel from blade view in Laravel

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I would like to export an Excel file from a blade Laravel view using [Laravel Excel](https://laravel-excel.maatwebsite.nl/3.1/exports/from-view.html) but I got this error:

```
Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\ExportController::view($id): Illuminate\Contracts\View\View must be compatible with Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView::view(): Illuminate\Contracts\View\View
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Contracts\View\View;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView;
use App\User;


class ExportController implements FromView
{

    public function view($id): View
    {
        return view('users.export', [
            'user' => User::find($id)
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('exportxls/{id}', 'ExportController@view');
```

**Blade File**

```
<table>My data is here...</table>
```

What is wrong ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are implementing Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromView you should override `view()` without any parameters.

```
public function view(): View
{
    return view('users.export');
}
```

Since you need `user_id`, you could try to pass it to the function in the URL. Something like:  `server/exportxls?user_id=2`

And then get it like:

```
$userId = request('user_id');
```

Check if this works for your case.

Comment: Got it! Thank you

Comment: Does it looks like this? public function view(): View
    {
        return view('users.export', [
            'user' => User::find(request('user_id'))
        ]);
    }